# Is there a Shortcut key to view Table Dependencies SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can we See the table dependencies by using shortcut keys from SQL Query Editor Itself.

I know we can use object explorer and then select the table , right click and then View Dependency .

But I juts want to navigate from Query Editor itself.

Comment: I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you select a table name in the query window of Sql Server Management Studio
and press ALT + F1 it will display the details of that table.

In the background shortcut key will execute sp_help on your behalf, so in this example it executes: sp_help users, which is much quicker than typing it.